# MEAN app - no logs

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

I have an application running on a node server. The application is running fine, but unfortunately I do not see any logs in the terminal window. When I do `npm start`, I get the following output in the terminal:

```
> app@0.1.0 start /Users/prerak/WebProjects/app/www
> grunt

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
Warning: Unable to read ".csslintrc" file (Error code: ENOENT). Used --force, continuing.

Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
```

I have some calls to `console.log` in my `server.js` file but I do not see them in the terminal. Is there anything else that I can do to get the logs?

For the application without any errors it's fine but if there are any issues, it's very difficult to debug the issue. In case of an error, I get the following in the logs:

```
> app@0.1.0 start /Users/prerak/WebProjects/app/www
> grunt

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
Warning: Unable to read ".csslintrc" file (Error code: ENOENT). Used --force, continuing.

Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I do not get any stackstace of the issue.

I have also configured my express server to show the stacktrace as:

```
var app = express();
app.set('showStackError', true);
```

I have this issue on Mac OSX 10.12 but if I run the same code on Ubuntu 14.10, it shows the logs in the terminal.

Also, instead of `npm start` if I do `node server.js` it shows the logs. What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Does replacing `console.log` with `console.warn` show the logs?

Comment: No, it does not show anything with `warn`.